# Java convert byte[] to int[] by concatenate every two bytes

Tags: java, arrays, int, byte, short

I have a `byte[ ]` array. How can i **concatenate every 2 byte** ( get 16 bit short sized value for everyone ) and **convert to int**?

I am converting by using a for loop, but my byte array is long, so for loop is making it slow.

*For example:*

byte array is like: `{0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04}`

I want concatenate every 2 byte as this: `{0x0001, 0x0102, 0x0304}`

Then get an **int[ ]** array, like this: `{ 1, 258, 772 }` and so on...

I can say in a nutshell, get short sized ( 16 bit ) value by concatenating two bytes, then cast it to int.

This is how i pass off for now, but it is slow:

```
byte[] buffer; // This is my byte array
int[] intBuffer = new int[buffer.length / 2];

for(int i = 0; i < buffer.length-1; i+=2){
    intBuffer[i/2] = ((buffer[i] << 8) | buffer[i+1]);
}
```

**Can I make this process faster by using Java libraries ?**

Thanks.

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll be able to make it *faster*. Whatever library you use will probably be doing the same thing you're doing now internally. Another option would be to do this lazily, if your application allows it. Specifically, have some `intBufferGet(i)` function that would return `(buffer[2*i] << 8) | buffer[2*i+1]`. That way you wouldn't have to precompute all of `intBuffer`. Whether this would work/help depends on the application though.

Comment: Thanks @arshajii, but i need complete of the array everytime. Actually, this byte array is a part of a stream and i need to convert it to int array continuously.

Comment: You could wrap this with a ByteBuffer you can convert to a ShortBuffer. This reads two bytes at a time and avoids the shifting. You could potentially use Unsafe if you need to go faster.

Comment: I can get ShortBuffer and short[ ] array by using `ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).asShortBuffer()`. This give me ShortBuffer, but i still need int[ ] for use it on image processing. 

I heard **Unsafe** from you firstly, i looked a little but dont have any idea for using this in array operations. Thanks for your recommendations @PeterLawrey.

Answer (score 0):

Using ByteBuffer to convert two bytes at a time.

```
public static int[] twoBytesToInts(byte[] bytes) {
    ShortBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).asShortBuffer();
    int[] ints = new int[buffer.remaining()];
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++)
        ints[i] = buffer.get(i) & 0xFFFF;
    return ints;
}
```

This uses `Unsafe` to read two bytes at a time to avoid shifts etc.

Using Unsafe directly to avoid creating objects you can do the following.

```
public static Unsafe getUnsafe() {
    try {
        Field theUnsafe = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        theUnsafe.setAccessible(true);
        return (Unsafe) theUnsafe.get(null);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}

public static int[] unsafeTwoBytesToInts(byte[] bytes) {
    Unsafe unsafe = getUnsafe();
    int[] ints = new int[bytes.length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++)
        ints[i] = Short.reverseBytes(
                unsafe.getShort(bytes, i * 2 + Unsafe.ARRAY_BYTE_BASE_OFFSET)) & 0xFFFF;
    return ints;
}
```

Running this with

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    byte[] bytes = {0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04};
    int[] ints = twoBytesToInts(bytes);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
    int[] ints2 = unsafeTwoBytesToInts(bytes);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints2));
}
```

prints

```
[1, 258, 772]
[1, 258, 772]
```

NOTE: If you read the code for `Short.reverseBytes` it appears that shifting occurs however on x86, the JIT replaces this code with an intrinsic machine code instruction to do the same thing.

```
public static int[] twoBytesToIntsOriginal(byte[] bytes) {
    int[] intBuffer = new int[bytes.length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length - 1; i += 2) {
        intBuffer[i / 2] = ((bytes[i] & 0xFF) << 8) | (bytes[i + 1] & 0xFF);
    }
    return intBuffer;
}
```

Running these through a JMH benchmark for a 32-byte byte[] doesn't show much difference.

```
Benchmark              Mode  Cnt   Score   Error   Units
Main.original         thrpt    5  45.552 ± 3.580  ops/us
Main.usingByteBuffer  thrpt    5  39.968 ± 9.818  ops/us
Main.usingUnsafe      thrpt    5  60.660 ± 9.234  ops/us
```

The cost of creating a ByteBuffer and ShortBuffer would be less important for large arrays, but this also points to another way to speed up the solution which is to reuse the `int[]` but return the length instead.

```
public static int unsafeTwoBytesToInts(byte[] bytes, int[] ints) {
    int len = bytes.length / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        ints[i] = Short.reverseBytes(
                unsafe.getShort(bytes, i * 2L + Unsafe.ARRAY_BYTE_BASE_OFFSET)) & 0xFFFF;
    return len;
}
```

with a throughput of

```
Main.usingUnsafe  thrpt    5  75.268 ± 9.119  ops/us
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `unsafe.getShort` calls be prone to unaligned memory access?

Comment: @E_net4wisheshappyholidays Depending on the JVM, this is possible, however in OpenJDK based JVMs, the bytes in the `byte[]` are always 32-bit aligned. On x86, x64, ARM, misaligned `short` reads are ok (possibly a little slower)

Comment: the unsafe version also need a `& 0xFFFF` to convert short into unsigned int. BTW, I wonder why `i * 2L + BASE_OFFSET` and `i * 2 + BASE_OFFSET` have significant difference on performance?

Comment: @yyyy the difference is in not allocating an `int[]` rather than using a `long`